# Format Post Date and Add Class

Tags: javascript, date, blogger

I have a date format in the following output that I get from Blogger:

```
<time class="published">14 March</time>
```

I would like to change its format, without modifying the output, to be something like this:

```
<time class="published"><span class="day">14</span><span class="month">Mar</span></time>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

## Update

As you are using the new themes, the procedure for changing the date format timestamp varies a bit. Add the following `b:includable` into the `b:widget` to which you want to change the timestamp -

```
<b:includable id='postTimestamp'>
  <span class='byline post-timestamp'>
    <data:byline.label />
    <b:if cond='data:post.url'>
      <meta expr:content='data:post.url.canonical' />
      <a class='timestamp-link' expr:href='data:post.url' rel='bookmark' title='permanent link'>
        <time class='published' expr:datetime='data:post.date.iso8601' expr:title='data:post.date.iso8601'>
          <b:eval expr='data:post.date format "dd MMM" '/>
        </time>
      </a>
    </b:if>
  </span>
</b:includable>
```

As you will notice, the format of the date is changed via the newly introduced `format` operator. For detailed documentation about the `format` operator -

> ### format(date, format)
>
> Formats the given date to the given format string, using the blog's
>   selected language.
>
> **date**: Date to be formatted, e.g. data:post.date
>
> **format**: [ICU format string](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table) for the date to be formatted to, in the
>   blog's language. e.g. "MMM dd".
>
> ```
> <b:eval expr='data:post.date format "MMM dd" ' />
> ```

There is currently no official documentation new themes, I referred to a [Blogger engineer's blog](https://so-how-do-i.blogspot.com/2017/03/change-my-post-timestamps-to-custom.html) for this information.

---

To achieve this, the date will have to be manipulated via JavaScript. In the theme code, you will see the code like -

```
<time class="published"><data:post.timestamp/></time>
```

Replace it with -

```
<time class="published"><script>dateconvert(new Date(&#39;<data:post.timestamp/>&#39;));</script></time>
```

And define the `dateconvert` function inside the `</head>` block -

```
<script>
   function dateconvert(date) {
    document.write("<span class='day'>" + date.getDate() + "</span> <span class='month'>" + date.toLocaleString("en-us", {month: "short"}) + '</span>')
  }
</script>
```

Comment: If using *toLocaleString* it would be much better to use *undefined* for the language so that the user sees it in the default language of their client. Otherwise, you might as well just leave it in English and not bother with a Date at all. ;-)

Comment: Hi Prayag, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately that's not possible on the recently added themes. Blogger uses different shortcode to add timestamp. It's now `<b:include data='{ items: [&quot;timestamp&quot;] }' name='headerBylineOverride'/>`, making it not possible to wrap `b:include` with `<script>dateconvert(new Date(&#39;`